# Misalignment in grammaticality judgements using gb4e due to added material

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, gb4e

I use gb4e for examples with grammaticality judgements. When I try to add material in the example environment, the numbering of the example misaligns. I am trying this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\textbf{Original sentence}
\ex[]{
\gll grammatischer satz \\
gramamtical sentence\\
\trans }
\textbf{Recalled sentence} 
\ex[*]{
\gll ungrammatischer satz.\\
ungrammatical sentence\\
\trans }
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

The additional line  \textbf{Recalled sentence} results in the 'b.' to be further to the left than the 'a.'. If I include the \textbf{Recalled sentence} in the judgment, like

```
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex[]{\textbf{Original sentence}
\gll grammatischer satz \\
gramamtical sentence\\
\trans }
\ex[*]{\textbf{Recalled sentence} 
\gll ungrammatischer satz.\\
ungrammatical sentence\\
\trans }
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
```

as expected, the * appears in front of Recalled sentence, and not the actual sentence. For some reason, the `linguex` package in the latest version does not run with my old TexLive, but newer TexLive versions don't run with my old Mac OS. So changing to `linguex` is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use free text inside the list environment. If you want unlabelled lines within the list, use `\sn` instead of `\ex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\sn[]{\textbf{Original sentence}}
\ex[]{
\gll grammatischer satz \\
gramamtical sentence\\
\trans }
\sn[]{\textbf{Recalled sentence} }
\ex[*]{
\gll ungrammatischer satz.\\
ungrammatical sentence\\
\trans }
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]